# Changing the state of nested objects in redux with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-router-dom

There is a problem when I add a new task to the state, it is added to the state of all projects.
How can I fix the problem. It is necessary that each project has its own state.

App.ts

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <App/>,
  },
  {
    path: 'project/:projectId',
    element: <ProjectItems/>
  }
])

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <RouterProvider router={router}/>
  </Provider>
);
```

ProjectItems.tsx

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

```
const ProjectItems = () => {
    const { projectId } = useParams();

    const tasks = useAppSelector(state => state.task);
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks))
    }, [tasks]);

    const addNewTask = () => {
        const newTask = {
            id: idGenerator(),
            title: prompt('')
        }
        dispatch(addTask({projectId, newTask}));
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.Main}>
                <button onClick={addNewTask}></button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProjectItems;
```

Project.tsx

Тут отрисовываю все проекты и вешаю на них сслыки

```
interface IProject {
    id: string,
    title: string | null,
}

const Project: FC<IProject> = ({title, id}) => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

    const handleDeleteProject = () => {
        dispatch(deleteProject({id}));    
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.Main}>
            <Link to={`project/${id}`}>
                <div className={styles.MainWrapper}>
                    {title}
                </div>
            </Link>
            <button onClick={handleDeleteProject}>Удалить</button>
        </div>  
    )
}

export default Project;
```

taskReducer.tsx

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

```
export enum TaskActions {
    ADD_TASK = 'ADD_TASK'
}

interface ITaskItem {
        id: string,
        title: string | null,
}

interface ITaskList {
    projectId: {
        tasks: ITaskItem[],
    }
}

interface IPayload {
    type: string,
    payload: {
        projectId: string,
        newTask: ITaskItem,
    },
}

const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks') || '[]');

const initialState: ITaskList = {
        projectId: {
            tasks: data
        }
}

export const taskReducer = (state = initialState, action: IPayload) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case TaskActions.ADD_TASK: {
            const { projectId, newTask } = action.payload;
            const newAddTasks = state.projectId.tasks;
            newAddTasks.push(newTask)
            return {
                ...state,
                [projectId]: {
                    ...state.projectId,
                    tasks: newAddTasks
                }
            }
        }
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

actionTask.tsx

```
import { TaskActions } from "../reducers/taskReducer"


export const addTask = (payload: any) => {     
    return {
        type: TaskActions.ADD_TASK,
        payload,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

With the way you've typed the tasks state it's all saved under a single `"projectId"` property.

```js
interface ITaskList {
  projectId: {
    tasks: ITaskItem[],
  }
}
```

The `ADD_TASK` reducer case grabs the `state.projectId.tasks` array and mutates it by pushing directly into it. It *then* saves this mutated `newAddTasks` array into the individual project's `tasks` array.

```js
case TaskActions.ADD_TASK: {
  const { projectId, newTask } = action.payload;
  const newAddTasks = state.projectId.tasks;
  newAddTasks.push(newTask) // <-- mutation!!
  return {
    ...state,
    [projectId]: {
      ...state.projectId,
      tasks: newAddTasks // <-- copy of all tasks
    }
  }
}
```

## Solution

Update the `taskReducer` to correctly compute the initial state and handle the `ADD_TASK` action.

```js
interface ITaskList {
  [projectId: string]: {
    tasks: ITaskItem[];
  };
}

// Access existing persisted state or provide empty object initial value
const initialState = JSON.parse(String(localStorage.getItem("tasks"))) || {};

export const taskReducer = (
  state: ITaskList = initialState,
  action: IPayload
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TaskActions.ADD_TASK: {
      const { projectId, newTask } = action.payload;

      return {
        ...state,
        [projectId]: {
          // Grab current tasks array or create new, then append new task
          tasks: (state[projectId]?.tasks ?? []).concat(newTask)
        }
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The `ProjectItems` component should be updated to read the *complete* tasks list (*for state persistence purposes you have there*), and then use the current `projectId` route path parameter to access *that* project's `tasks` array.

```
const ProjectItems = () => {
  const { projectId } = useParams();

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  // All tasks in state
  const allTasks = useAppSelector((state) => state.tasks);

  // This project's tasks
  const tasks = allTasks[projectId]?.tasks ?? [];

  useEffect(() => {
    // Persist all tasks state to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(allTasks));
  }, [allTasks]);

  const addNewTask = () => {
    const newTask = {
      id: idGenerator(),
      title: prompt("")
    };
    dispatch(addTask({ projectId, newTask }));
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.Main}>
      <button onClick={addNewTask}>Add New Task</button>
      <ul>
        {tasks.map((task) => (
          <li key={task.id}>{task.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit clever-knuth-gxtx47]

Comment: Возникает такая ошибка taskReducer.ts:47 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tasks'

Comment: And sometimes such an Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: @Gumblll Sorry about that, I didn't reset the persisted `tasks` value in localStorage. New guards are in place, please check again.

Comment: Everything works fine, thanks for your time)

Comment: @Gumblll Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!